# Performing an airport scan on my Mac for available WiFi networks pulls up multiple SSID with different mac address. What's going on?

Tags: network, hardware, wireless

I performed the following command to search for available WiFi networks in my apartment complex:

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan | grep OBC`

I `grep`'d the `OBC` network because there should be 3, accurately labeled 1, 2, and 3. However, when I performed this command, I received the following output:

`OBC Wifi 3 c2:9f:db:f3:ef:d8 -74  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
OBC Wifi 1 c6:9f:db:f3:ef:d8 -74  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
OBC Wifi 2 ca:9f:db:f3:ef:d8 -75  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
OBC Wifi 1 c2:9f:db:f5:62:66 -70  1       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
OBC Wifi 2 c2:9f:db:f5:67:f4 -50  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)`

A little backstory may be important here. First of all, these 3 WAPs are Ubiquiti Unify APs and are numbered according to the LAN they occupy. Therefore, there are 3 separate networks and each has a WAP that is associated with it. These WAPs are addressed as follows:

`OBC Wifi 1 = DC:9F:DB:F4:62:66
OBC Wifi 2 = DC:9F:DB:F4:67:F4
OBC Wifi 3 = DC:9F:DB:F2:EF:D8`

Note that the SSIDs that came up are very similar to Ubiquiti mac addresses and also very similar to each other. Also note that when I go into the router and look at the DHCP table, I see nothing relating to these mac addresses OR the IPs that have been designated for the WAPs. One last thing to note is that these WAPs (as well as the routers) are all physically located in 3 different places (so 6 different places total). The routers are in 3 different outbuildings and the WAPs are equidistant from each other.

So the question is, have these 3 networks or WAPs been compromised or is something just screwy with the WAP configurations? These used to work perfectly and I've never seen scan results like these. Suggestions? Comments? Thanks!

Comment: Looks normal to me: ESSIDs `OBC Wifi 1` and `OBC Wifi 2` each have two physical access points (BSSIDs) associated with them, while `OBC Wifi 3` only has one.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to networking. How is that normal? Shouldn't they only have one BSSID each? Especially since `OBC Wifi 3` only has one? They're each the same type of hardware and the BSSID doesn't match the mac address I listed?

Comment: They should have one BSSID per physical location.

Comment: There are only 3 physical WAPS, so what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Ubiquiti APs use generated MAC addresses for the bridge interface (bridging wireless to ethernet). So, you'll often see similar MACs (but not quite the same). A single AP has two MACs in the configuration I often see.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html

The MAC addresses you posted (if you didn't alter them) do not even come up as valid and being owned by anyone (delegated).  So they could be setup just for this airport, or could be rogue. :/